# Add attribute to the association class ManyToMany

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I use Symfony and Doctrine for mapping database , I have 2 entities "Product" and "Operation" with ManyToMany relation so I get an other table in DataBase called "Products-Operations"
Now I like to add an attribute for this table , how can I do it?

**Produit.orm.yml**

```
manyToMany:
    operations:
        targetEntity: Operation
        mappedBy: produits
```

**Operation.orm.yml**

```
manyToMany:
    produits:
        targetEntity: Produit
        inversedBy: operations
        joinTable:
            name: produits_operations
            joinColumns:
                operation_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                produit_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider adding a row to that m:n-table. If you look at how you use that [table with Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) you will see that there is no Entity attached to it. Therefore the property is not really accessible. On the other hand if you want to create an Entity for it, now modelling the association between the 3 entities becomes strange. Instead try to think if the property shouldn't be attached to one of the entities instead.

Comment: Often when you are in this type of situation, it means you are missing an abstraction in between those 2 models. Pure many to many relations are not so common. So like dbrumann says, if you need some properties in the 'link' table, you will need a 3rd entity

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me how will be the relations between these 3 entities if I add a new Entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with annotation to create table in data base I think same orm.yml and hope this solution is work...

```
//inverse side
class Product 
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductOperation", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
   */  
  private $productOperations;
}
//owing side
class ProductOperation 
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productOperations") 
   */ 
  private $product;
   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Operation", inversedBy="productOperations") 
   */ 
  private $operation;

  }
//inverse side
class Operation
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductOperation", mappedBy="operation", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
   */  
  private $productOperations;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the solution, I tried this and that is work fine, thakns @Farshad

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah Your Welcome